# Setting font on spinner not working

Tags: android, fonts, spinner

I am trying to set font on spinner as follows:

```
final Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/futura-medium.ttf");
ArrayAdapter<String> hoursAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.spinner_item){
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.spinnertext)).setTypeface(font);
        return view;
    }
    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
        ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.spinnertext)).setTypeface(font);
        return view;
    }
};
```

The scenario is like app language is GE_SS_Unique_Light an Arabic font and changing only spinner font but it's working fine. When I tried with other fonts.
Any suggestions ?

Comment: `not working` , `But its work fine` please decide if it is working, or not.

Comment: I mean its working fine when I tested with other font like futura-medium.ttf

Comment: What is the result when you set this font? How exactly it is not working?

Comment: It might be the problem with the font file that you downloaded. Try to download from different source and try again.

Comment: means dat is not taking effect at all

Comment: so it stays with the default font? Are you sure that the font has the characters, you are trying to use?

Comment: ya that and all are fine